# Python newbie class design question

Tags: python, oop, iterator

I'm trying to figure out the best way to design a couple of classes.  I'm pretty new to Python (and OOP in general) and just want to make sure that I'm doing this right.  I have two classes: "Users" and "User".

```
class User(object):
   def __init__(self):
       pass

class Users(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.users = []

   def add(self, user_id, email):
       u = User()
       u.user_id = user_id
       u.email = email
       self.users.append(u)

users = Users()
users.add(user_id = 1, email = 'bob@example.com')
```

If I want to retrieve my users, I use:

```
for u in users.users:
    print u.email
```

"users.users" seems to be a bit redundant.  Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this in your `Users`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.users)
```

Now you can:

```
for u in users:
    print u.email
```

[Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

Answer (score 17):

I would say not really. Your `Users` class appears to just be a list of users, so I would just make it a list rather than a whole class. Here's what I would do:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, user_id=None, email=None):
        self.user_id, self.email = user_id, email

users = []
users.append(User(user_id = 1, email = 'bob@example.com'))

for u in users:
    print u.email
```

If you want `Users` to be a class of its own for some other reason, you could have it inherit from `list`, or (if not) you could add these to the definition:

```
class Users(object):
    # rest of code
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.users)
```

That way, you can simply say:

```
users = Users()
...
for u in users:
    print u.email
```

Comment: TypeError: iteration over non-sequence -- if you're using += the RHS should also be a list.

Answer (score 6):

You probably just want a list of User objects rather than a class which contains multiple users.

```
class User(object):
   def __init__(self, user_id, email):
       self.user_id = user_id
       self.email = email

users = []
users.append(User(user_id = 1, email = 'bob@example.com'))
```

All member attributes for User should reside in the User class, not the Users class.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with users.users, but if you prefer a nicer way to do it you could override [`__iter__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) in Users.

```
class Users(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.users = []

   def add(self, user_id, email):
       u = User()
       u.user_id = user_id
       u.email = email
       self.users.append(u)

   def __iter__(self):
       return iter(self.users)
```

Now you can do this:

```
for u in users:
    print u.email
```

The `__iter__` special method makes your object behave as an iterator

Answer (score 1):

There's no "black" and "white" here, just shades of grey. You don't need a special `Users` class if it's just going to be a list.

Another way:

```
class User:
    all_users = []

    def __init__(self, id, email):
        self.id = id # No need to call it user_id - it's a User object, after all!
        self.email = email
        self.all_users.append(self) #automatically add to list of all users

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s(%s)' % (self.id, self.email)
```

Then, if you typed the above into `user.py`:

```
>>> from user import *
>>> bob = User('bob', 'bob@test.com')
>>> alice = User('alice', 'alice@test.com')
>>> for u in User.all_users:
...     print u
...
bob(bob@test.com)
alice(alice@test.com)
>>>
```

Just an example to get you thinking.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `self.all_users.append(self)` or even `A.all_users.append(self)` (both work) instead of `self.users.append(self)`?